# error creando un pdf con jspdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Esta simple web es para probar jspdf.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title> creando pdfs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">

    <script src="js/jspdf.js"></script>
    <script src="js/FileSaver.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1> creando un pdf</h1>

  <script>
    function creapdf(){
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
      doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
      doc.addPage();
      doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');
      doc.save('test.pdf');
    }
  </script>

<a href="javascript:creapdf()">Download PDF</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Me devuelve un error. `saveAs` is not defined.

He visto esta respuesta que parece que solucciona el problema
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340194/doc-save-throwing-error-with-jspdf

Sin embargo, aunque tengo lincada las librerías

```
<script src="js/jspdf.js"></script>
<script src="js/FileSaver.js"></script>
```

continúa devolviéndome el error.

Comment: No puedo reproducir tu error. Que explorador estas usando? y que versiones del `jspdf` y `FileSaver` tienes? Por otro lado, tampoco fue necesario usar `FileSaver.js` en mi caso.

Comment: jsPDF-0.9.0rc2 ---- Chrome 48  ---Firefox 44

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que se lo que sucede. Copia el archivo `jspdf.min.js` que se encuentra dentro de la carpeta `dist`. Luego lo agregas

```
<script src="js/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

y debería funcionar.

Borra `<script src="js/FileSaver.js"></script>`, no lo necesitas con la versión de navegadores que estas utilizando.

No te funcionaba porque el archivo `jspdf.js` que estabas utilizando no era el archivo final. En general, cuando descargues una de estas librerías utiliza los archivos que se encuentren en la carpeta dist, que por convención tiene los archivos finales en sus versiones minificada y para debug.